# SQL 2000: change collation of model database only- not master

Tags: sql-server-2000

One of our production SQL 2000 server has windows collation for master and msdb but SQl collation for model and tempdb.
We are trying to have the same setup on a test environment which at the moment has windows collation for all system databases
So, I got a copy of the model database with SQL collation from another server and did the following:

1. restored it as another user database (model2).
2. shut down the SQL service
3. moved the model database files (model.mdf and modellog.ldf) to another location
4. Renamed model2 database files as model.mdf and modellog.ldf so that SQL will think that this is the existing database.

It did change the collation but when I right click on model database and click on properties...it shows the following error:

> "Cannot resolve collation conflict for equal to operation"

Which it doesn't show in the existing production server.

Please help
Regards

Manjot

Answer (score 1):

I was restoring database using management studio and not enterprise manager.
I could restore model using enterprise manager without any problem.